# How to forge and encode session cookie

Tags: flask, cookies, jwt, session-cookies, penetration-testing

I am doing penetration testing on a website (localhost) and would like to know how to encode dictionary into correct jwt (session cookie?) format. I am completely new to web hacking and pen testing.

I have been given the source code. The part of the flask application is as follows:

```
@blueprint.route('/control-robot', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def control_robot():
    great_mission= NewMission()
    form = forms.NewMissionForm(request.form)
    form.bot.choices = [('1', '2')]
    print("#########################################")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(great_mission)
        session['great_mission'] = pickle.dumps(great_mission)
        session['return_url'] = url_for('base_blueprint.control_robot')
        print("#97")
        return redirect(url_for('base_blueprint.security_key_confirm'))
    print(session)
    if 'great_mission' in session:
        great_mission_txt = session.pop('great_mission', None)
        print(great_mission_txt)
        print("inside #103")
        if(session.pop('verified', 0) < datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()-5):
            flash('missing security key authentication', 'danger')
        elif great_mission_txt:
            great_mission = pickle.loads(great_mission_txt)
            return config('FLAG')
    print("#109")
    return render_template('sites/control-robot.html', form=form)
```

The sitemap is as follows: `dashboard->control_robot`

if I click on "control_robot" on dashboard, then it executes above code and displays the form to be filled.

Following is the output on flask localhost debugging session after clicking on "control_robot":

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
#########################################
<SecureCookieSession {'_fresh': True, '_id': 'ac1fcdef2c723257845d917bde568828b61069af207d0677376e397b930a7060528608493f4c965cb3c06c07cdd2345ba49acc56efb1a695515d9c11ec3469ae', '_user_id': '1', 'csrf_token': '1f67b99fd698b9eec3858c818f5722713a31fc4a'}>
#109
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2021 14:04:59] "GET /control-robot HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Notice the form dictionary is blank as no form has been filled. I want to get to the flag. Notice the second if condition, which checks if 'great_mission' key is present in the session. My idea is to forge the session cookie by including "great_mission" key and send the get request like:

```
cs = s.get(url + "control-robot", cookies = {"session":"new cookie"})
```

I get session cookie in following format:

```
.eJwljktqBDEMRO_idRaWZf3mMo0tS8wQSKB7ZhVy93HIsgrq1fspR55x3cvteb7ioxyPVW5lOKSvyObSsJFop2UgcwWxatPJUNlGtiqrsggKB5pMwzqkcqWmXLUbZndj8ole2av4Wg07zdFtuBNHThhsRLD5DhCOfXOjbJHXFee_Dezo15nH8_szvv6K5P1ludh0WuyVkrqCJklrAjhw-_dRft9jlD5c.YZax6g.tS__qotCbmnLiJgutCjo5R-q3o0
```

I assume this is in jwt format, thus I used flask decode which gives me following output:

```
$ flask-unsign --decode --cookie '.eJwljktqBDEMRO_idRaWZf3mMo0tS8wQSKB7ZhVy93HIsgrq1fspR55x3cvteb7ioxyPVW5lOKSvyObSsJFop2UgcwWxatPJUNlGtiqrsggKB5pMwzqkcqWmXLUbZndj8ole2av4Wg07zdFtuBNHThhsRLD5DhCOfXOjbJHXFee_Dezo15nH8_szvv6K5P1ludh0WuyVkrqCJklrAjhw-_dRft9jlD5c.YZax6g.tS__qotCbmnLiJgutCjo5R-q3o0'
{'_fresh': True, '_id': 'ac1fcdef2c723257845d917bde568828b61069af207d0677376e397b930a7060528608493f4c965cb3c06c07cdd2345ba49acc56efb1a695515d9c11ec3469ae', '_user_id': '1', 'csrf_token': '1f67b99fd698b9eec3858c818f5722713a31fc4a'}
```

is there any way to encode dictionary in above format, assuming I have the secret key?

and am I doing this correctly, if no what is the correct way to achieve this?